# How to split and append the data in Python in a single excel column?

Tags: python-3.x, split, append

Here is input:
[This is my input in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNN9f.png)

I would require the output in the below format:
[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aiyrn.png)

I got the correct code for splitting the column 'person',but i'm not able get the required format.

Could anybody guide me to get the required output format.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: hi @Nathanial i have used this code to split the data:`split_data=pd.concat([data,data["Person"].str.split(",| and",expand=True)],axis=1)`, but after splitting **i'm unable to append it as per my requirement**.